# Group by Week of year (Week number) in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, week-number

In regular SQL i could do something like

```
SELECT * From T GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, T.Date)
```

How can i do that in Linq to SQL ?

The following don't work

```
From F In DB.T Group R By DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, F.Date)
```

Also don't work:

```
From F In DB.T Group R By (F.Date.DayOfYear / 7)
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean?  Doesn't compile, doesn't return expected results?

Comment: doesnt compile.. "Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments."

Comment: ok, the answer is "From F In DB.T Group R By WeekOfYear = (F.Date.DayOfYear / 7)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763056.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx) does not support the [Calendar.WeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(VS.71).aspx) method, but you could potentially create a TSQL [function that wraps the call to DatePart](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/01/datepartweek-with-linq-to-sql.html). The DayOfYear / 7 trick should work for most cases and is much easier to use. Here's the code I ended up with:

```
var x = from F in DB.T
        group F by new {Year = F.Date.Year, Week = Math.Floor((decimal)F.Date.DayOfYear / 7)} into FGroup
        orderby FGroup.Key.Year, FGroup.Key.Week
        select new {
            Year = FGroup.Key.Year,
            Week = FGroup.Key.Week,
            Count = FGroup.Count()
        };
```

Results in something like this:

```
Year    Week    Count
2004    46      3
2004    47      3
2004    48      3
2004    49      3
2004    50      2
2005    0       1
2005    1       8
2005    2       3
2005    3       1
2005    12      2
2005    13      2
```

Comment: Just remember that this will not directly correspond to to the Calendar weeks, as it assumes the year always starts on a Sunday. To match up fully you would need to use the Calendar.WeekOfYear or wrap the DatePart call into a SQL Function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SqlFunctions.DatePart` method from the [System.Data.Entity.SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_DatePart_System_String_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__) namespace.

```
// Return the week number
From F In DB.T Group R By SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", F.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works correctly.

```
from F in DB.T group F by F.Date.DayOfYear / 7;
```

You were specifying the group by incorrectly.  The result of this code be a collection of objects.  Each object will have a Key property which will be what you grouped by (in this case the result of `F.Date.DayOfYear / 7`.  Each object will be a collection of objects from T that  met the group condition.

Comment: all i had to do was "From F In DB.T Group R By WeekOfYear = (F.Date.DayOfYear / 7)"  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the culture you are in the following code will take that into account:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var cal = ci.Calendar;
var rule = ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
var firstDayOfWeek = ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

var groups = from F in DB.T
             group F by cal.GetWeekOfYear(F, rule, firstDayOfWeek) into R
             select R;
```

Comment: this dont work-- "Method 'Int32 GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule, System.DayOfWeek)' has no supported translation to SQL."

Comment: It seems that Calendar.GetWeekOfYear isn't support in Linq2Sql or Linq to Entities; you would have the pull the whole data set out first then use cal.GetWeekOfYear(x, rule, firstDayOfWeek).

Comment: yes.. but dividing DayOfYear by 7 is enough for my needs. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the date of the first day in the week.

To get the date of the first day in the week.
you can use this code:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

Then you can group by the first date of the week.

So this code in regular SQL :

```
SELECT * From T GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, T.Date)
```

can be done in  Linq to SQL like this

```
T.GroupBy(i => i.Date.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday));
```