# c# get all dates from database that appear with current week

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

trying to get all the dates from the db that are within the current week

i have email1DueDate, email2DueDate, email3DueDate

and i want to see if they are due to be sent within the current week

Comment: Would you like to know the SQL or LINQ way to do it?

Comment: Did you visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427898/group-by-week-of-year-week-number-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: linq please, bjornruysen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should calculate two DateTime values for the start of the week and the end of the week, you can do that like this (assuming Monday is the first day):

```
DateTime startOfWeek = DateTime.Today;
int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - startOfWeek.DayOfWeek;
startOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(delta);

DateTime endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(7);
```

next you can use this in your LINQ query to get the results you need, I am assuming you want results to be rows that have any of your due dates fall in the week:

```
var results = DB.Table.Where(x =>
    (x.email1DueDate >= startOfWeek && x.email1DueDate < endOfWeek) ||
    (x.email2DueDate >= startOfWeek && x.email2DueDate < endOfWeek) ||
    (x.email3DueDate >= startOfWeek && x.email3DueDate < endOfWeek)
    );
```

If this is not what you need then you will need to clarify your requirements

Answer (score 1):

LINQ

```
listOfDates.Where(x => x.email1DueDate > beginOfWeekDate && x.email1DueDate < endOfWeekDate).ToList();
```

Of course you'll still have to figure out the begin and end dates